# use default image in place of broken image url - Js/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Requirement:
I need to replace broken image url link with the default one I give.

```
        $(body).find('.timeline_profile_image').css({ "background-image": "url('" + doesImageExists(ajax_based_profile_image) + "')" });
```

in my `doesImageExists()`, I check if the image url has image and then based on that true|false, I want to return URL to add in above expression.

Here is my function:

```
async function doesImageExists(image_url) {
    let updated_image_url = image_url;
    await $.ajax({
        url: image_url,
        type: 'get',
        async: true,
        error: function(response) {
            this.updated_image_url = no_image_path;
        }
    });
    return updated_image_url
}
```

also tried:

```
function doesImageExists(image_url) {
    let returnUrl;
    $.get(image_url)
        .done(function() {
            // Do something now you know the image exists.
            console.log('success block')
            returnUrl = image_url;
            return returnUrl;
        }).fail(function() {
            // Image doesn't exist - do something else.
            console.log('fail block')
            returnUrl = no_image_path;
            return returnUrl;
        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log('then block')
            returnUrl = result;
            console.log(result);
            return report_url;
        });
    console.log(returnUrl);
    return returnUrl;
}
```

*Problem*
both of above functions show proper output as long as I work inside that function but I need to return value so that it can be used later by the other functions.

Comment: Well you can not return from an asynchronous method. And you are not treating the call as asynchronous. You are not using `await` where you call the function.

Comment: how can i get return string to be used later. I dont care if its an async call or anything else.

Comment: `await  doesImageExists(ajax_based_profile_image)`

Comment: Or just use a promise....

Comment: could you please write code for that. I have no clue about this. as you can see, I am using it to append image as background to my cloned element